# Reading XML file in FME?

Tags: fme-form, xml

I want the below xml file to be read by fme.

I tried reading documents and seeing videos. This xml looks more complicated.

http://pastebin.com/pXmjwEqW

```
<InspectObjects>
<Object id="197589" action="update" objectType="pole" DataSetName="electric"     UniverseId="0" WorldId="0">
<Attributes>
<Attribute id="asset_id"></Attribute>
<Attribute id="id">197589</Attribute>
<Attribute id="location_description">A.T.L.</Attribute>
<Attribute id="npcl_ct">False</Attribute>
```

I have different objects in a single xml file. I want to filter based on "objectType".

How this can be done by using xml parsing in FME?

Comment: pastebin is blocked (at work) but been doing lots of xml parsing in FME lately can you put a snippet in your question please.

Comment: Please see the edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the attributes you need the [xmlflattener](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/xmlflattener.htm)

> "Flattens content of XML element(s) into feature attributes.
>
> This transformer provides a quick and easy way to output any content
>   or attributes of an XML element as feature attributes by specifying
>   the element name or path. Optionally, the XML attributes from the
>   ancestors of the specified elements can be fetched as FME attributes
>   as well."

A good reference
https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Reading-Complex-XML-or-GML-using-the-XMLFlattener

Comment: Great Thanks. Really informative and helpful. Will check and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a [previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152757), use the XMLFlattener.  In the the Expose Attributes parameter of the transformer, be sure to expose the "Object.objectType" attribute (you can rename the attribute with the AttributeRenamener if you like) You can then use filtering and testing transformers on this new attribute.

This looks like FieldSmart XML.  It is not clear what are you doing with the data.

Answer (score 2):

Now FME has made it very easy to extract the XML (and Json) elements at the reader level. This is just an update since the question was asked in 2015 and the latest version of FME is 2018.

[image]

You could flatten your file here as well

[image]

[image]

[image]